# Laravel get model optional with or separately?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have:

**ItemRepo**

```
class ItemRepo {
    ...

    public function findByNameAndDate($name, Carbon $date, $with = null) {
        $item = Item::where('name', $name)->where(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), $date->toDateString());
        if($with) {
            $item->with($with);
        }
        return $item->first();
    }
}
```

Which is called from:

**ItemController**

```
...
use App\Repos\ItemRepo;
...

class ItemController extends Controller
{
    protected $repo;

    function __construct() {
        $this->repo = new ItemRepo();
    }

    public function show($day, $month, $year, $name) {
        $date = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day);
        $item = $this->repo->findByNameAndDate($name, $date, 'likes');
        return $item;
    }
}
```

You see I have an optional `$with` parameter for when I want to bring back any relationships, in this case I wanted all the likes for an item.

Is this the right way to do it? or would it be better to simply get the Item model, then pass that model to a `LikeRepo` that e.g. has a function called `countLikes` or `getLikes`. However in that case you are doing two queries and not a single larger one (which is why I am unsure of which is the best way to go).

Comment: Do you always use likes as relationship or there are multiple possibility?

Comment: Why is your `findByNameAndDate` not a scope function? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes Besides I don't like that you initialize your Model in the constructor. Actually I don't think I have ever came  across an initliazation of a model in the docs.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jedrzej/withable - it's a laravel package for Eloquent that lets you load selected relations with parameters passed in the URL or just by passing a list of relations to load

Comment: @Daan I have made it a repo so I can completely separate the database stuff from my controllers (easy to test and switch out the database). It's not really a model.

Comment: @gbalduzzi Multiple possibilities.

Comment: I also just thought isn't it undoing to point of having a repo if we use scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always `load` the relationships later:

```
$item = $this->repo->findByNameAndDate($name, $date)->load('likes');
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this.